# How to inject instance depending on the final injection chain target?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have classes: `X1 <- Y <- Z <- Config` (arrow means injection via constructor) and `X2 <- Y <- Z <- Config`. `Z` expects some configuration (`Config` class), but the instance depends on the final type: `X1` and `X2` (type itself or a key they have defned somehow). In this example there should be two different instances of each `Y`, `Z` and `Config` class.

How can I use different `Config` in `Z` depending on where it finally is used (`X1` or `X2`)?

```
    class X1
    {
        public X1(Y y)
        {
            int c = y.Z.Config.C; // This config variable is connected with X1.
        }
    }

    class X2
    {
        public X2(Y y)
        {
            int c = y.Z.Config.C; // This config variable is different than the one for X1.
        }
    }

    class Y
    {
        public Z Z { get; }

        public Y(Z z)
        {
            Z = z;
        }
    }


    class Z
    {
        public Config Config { get; }

        public Z(Config config)
        {
            Config = config;
        }
    }

    class Config
    {
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
```

I could do sth like below, but it seems very fishy and smelly (a rough example):

```
    Bind<Config>().ToMethod(x =>
    {
        // Return proper config object depending on the classes found in the injection chain...
        IRequest req = x.Request;
        while (req != null)
        {
            if (req.Service.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(X1))
            {
                return configForX1;
            }

            if (req.Service.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(X2))
            {
                return configForX2;
            }

            req = req.ParentRequest;
        }

        throw new Exception("Oh no.");
    });
```

Or to make it less fishy should I do:

```
    class X1
    {
        public X1([Named("X1")] Config config, Y y)
        {
            y.SetConfig(config);
        }
    }

    class Y
    {
        private readonly Z _z;

        public Y(Z z)
        {
            _z = z;
        }

        public void SetConfig(Config config)
        {
            _z.SetConfig(config);
        }
    }

    class Z
    {
        private Config _config;

        public void SetConfig(Config config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
    }
```

and

```
    Bind<MetricsApiConfiguration>().To().Named("X1");
    Bind<MetricsApiConfiguration>().To().Named("X2");
```

Any other (better) ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a behaviour similar to `WhenInjectedInto` ? https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-the-built-in-attribute-based-helpers

Comment: @jbl Yes, but WhenInjectedInto checks the class which item is injected into directly, it does not traverse the injection chain. This means writing `.WhenInjectedInto<X1>()` will not work since `Config` is not injected into `X1` directly, but into `Z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WhenInjectedInto` is close, but as you noted, only looks at the current request. I created an extension method to address this exact use case:

```
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenAnyAncestorIs<T>(this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding, params Type[] types)
    {
        bool Matches(IRequest request)
        {
            Type target = request.Target?.Member?.ReflectedType;
            return (target != null && types.Any(t => t == target))
                || (request.ParentRequest != null && Matches(request.ParentRequest));
        }

        return binding.When(Matches);
    }
```

and use like:

```
Bind<IConfigSource>().To<DataConfigSource>()
    .WhenAnyAncestorIs(
        typeof(DataConfigurationRepository),
        typeof(ManifestRepository),
        typeof(DataManager)
    )
    .InSingletonScope();
```

you will need an additional binding for requests that do not use those Types.